# Evolving limit in multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I think this is probably easy to evaluate, but I can't see any solution here (the answer is $ 0$, so I tried to find a limited function, but, apparently, that is not the right path):

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{x \over \sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use $x=r\cos\Theta‎$ and $y=r\sin\Theta‎$ you will see limit exists and is equal to $0$
$\lim \limits_{r \to 0}{r\cos\Theta‎ \over \sqrt[3]{(r\cos\Theta‎)^2+(r\sin\Theta)^2}}=\lim \limits_{r \to 0}{r\cos\Theta‎ \over r^\frac{2}{3}\sqrt[3]{(\cos^2\Theta+\sin^2\Theta}}=\lim \limits_{r \to 0}{r^\frac{1}{3}\cos\Theta‎ \over \sqrt[3]{(\cos^2\Theta+\sin^2\Theta}}=0 $

Comment: Using these, how do I change the limit, I mean, $ r $ and $ \theta $ tend to what values?

Comment: Now see it. i edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this without using a polar conversion. Notice that
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}} \right| \leq 
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left| \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} \right| = 
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \left| x^{1/3} \right| = 0.
$$